# Persistence in an OSGi environment using Datanucleus JDO and blueprints

Tags: osgi, jdo, datanucleus, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

I am trying to do persistence in an OSGi environment (Karaf running Felix) with as much modularity as possible. I chose JDO for its added features (mainly fetch groups) instead of JPA. The implementation being Datanucleus. I use Maven to build the whole project.

As I didn't have any prior experience with JDO or OSGi it was quite a challenge to make either of them work. I am presently able to do JDO persistence in a Java SE environment (unit tests work without a problem) and I know how to provide services in an OSGi environment using the blueprint container. But I am not able to make those two things work together. I am having classloading issues.

I was not able to build even a simple application that would be able to do JDO persistence on Karaf (I tried following [this tutorial](http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/wiki/display/USERS/HOWTO+Use+Datanucleus+with+OSGi+and+Spring+DM) but it uses Spring DM and I was unable to rewrite it to use OSGi blueprint instead).

What I am most confused about is:

- What value should I set the *datanucleus.primaryClassLoader* property to?
- What class loader to pass as an argument to the *JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory* method?
- What packages to explicitly import using the *maven-bundle-plugin*? (looks like at least *javax.jdo*, *org.datanucleus.api.jdo* and *org.osgi.framework* might be required)
- What do the other bundles need besides a reference to *PersistenceManagerFactory*?

Additionally:

- Is it possible to separate the persistence info from the value classes? If I understand it correctly, that would only be possible if using runtime enhancement which would be very complicated if at all doable.
- Is it possible to define interdependent persistence capable classes in multiple bundles? Such as having Users defined in one bundle and their Addresses in another?

I would be extremely grateful for an example of a simple multi-bundle project that takes care of persistence using only Datanucleus, JDO API and OSGi blueprint.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can only provide some basic hints about getting JDO/datanucleus to work on top of Karaf.

As pointed in the tutorial, you'll need to extend the `LocalPersistenceManagerFactoryBean`, implementing as well the `BundleContextAware` interface.

The key point here is classloading: the `LocalPersistenceManagerFactoryBean` expects all classes to be loaded by one single classloader, which isn't the case in a OSGi runtime.

In order to get it working you'll need to:

1. Explicitly import the `org.datanucleus.api.jdo` in your manifest file.
2. The `datanucleus.primaryClassLoader` property could be set to the same classloader you'll pass to the `JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory` method. The classloader is the one used by the `org.datanucleus.api.jdo` bundle (see example below)
3. You'll need to set the `datanucleus.plugin.pluginRegistryClassName` property to `org.datanucleus.plugin.OSGiPluginRegistry`.
4. When stopping/uninstalling your bundle, you'll have to refresh the `javax.jdo` bundle for avoiding errors when re-creating the persistence manager factory (check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19524534/831797) on the subject)

**Sample custom LocalPersistenceManagerFactoryBean:**

```java
public class OSGiLocalPersistenceManagerFactoryBean
    extends LocalPersistenceManagerFactoryBean implements BundleContextAware {

    public static final String JDO_BUNDLE_NAME    = "org.datanucleus.api.jdo";
    public static final String JDO_PMF_CLASS_NAME = "org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory";

    private BundleContext bundleContext;

    @Override
    protected PersistenceManagerFactory newPersistenceManagerFactory(String name) {
        return JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(name, getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    protected PersistenceManagerFactory newPersistenceManagerFactory(Map props) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClassLoader();

        props.put("datanucleus.primaryClassLoader", classLoader);

        if (FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()) != null) { // running in OSGi
            props.put("datanucleus.plugin.pluginRegistryClassName", "org.datanucleus.plugin.OSGiPluginRegistry");
        }

        PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(props, classLoader);

        return pmf;
    }

    private ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
        ClassLoader classLoader = null;
        Bundle thisBundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass());

        if (thisBundle != null) { // on OSGi runtime
            Bundle[] bundles = bundleContext.getBundles();

            for (Bundle bundle : bundles) {
                if (JDO_BUNDLE_NAME.equals(bundle.getSymbolicName())) {
                    try {
                        classLoader = bundle.loadClass(JDO_PMF_CLASS_NAME).getClassLoader();
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        // do something fancy here ...
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else { // on Java runtime
            classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        }
        return classLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void setBundleContext(BundleContext bundleContext) {
        this.bundleContext = bundleContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also please note that all datanucleus bundles must be started when starting your bundle. If not so gives an error (NullPointerException) in OSGIPluginRegistry.