# OSGi: refresh one bundle when other is updated

Tags: osgi

Recently I came across [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19524534/831797) where I had to refresh bundle A whenever bundle B is updated.

Would it be possible to refresh bundle A on B's activator?

Is it considered a good practice?

Any other suggestions on how to approach such a problem?

Comment: Which runtime are you using?

Comment: I'm using karaf 2.2.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would not be good practice to refresh bundle A in bundle B's activator since you couple them directly.

Bundle A must have a dependency on bundle B. After updating B, you can [refresh bundle B](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r5/core/org/osgi/framework/wiring/FrameworkWiring.html#refreshBundles%28java.util.Collection,%20org.osgi.framework.FrameworkListener...%29) which will also refresh B's [dependency closure](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r5/core/org/osgi/framework/wiring/FrameworkWiring.html#getDependencyClosure%28java.util.Collection%29) which should include A.